# Where condition Not Working with in Mysql Search

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is MySQL Query in codeignitor

```
$query = $this->db->select('stu_id as id, CONCAT(UCASE(stu_fname), " ", UCASE(stu_mname), " ", UCASE(stu_lname), " - ", stu_id) as text')
                    ->like('stu_fname', $this->input->get("q"), 'after')
                    ->or_like('stu_mname', $this->input->get("q"), 'after')
                    ->or_like('stu_lname', $this->input->get("q"), 'after')
                    ->where('stu_status', '0')
                    ->limit(10)
                    ->from('student')
                    ->get();
```

everything works fine and i am getting the search results but `WHERE` condition is not working in this and rows with `stu_status = 1` are not being omitted, here i only want rows with `stu_status = 0` . Can anyone help what's going wrong ?

Comment: check this if you are on CI 3.x: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Comment: I don't know codeignitor but the `like` should already have a `where` built so I'd guess the `where(` adds a second `where` making it invalid. The `mysqli` tag seems unrelated here.

Comment: If you want to see the sql that CI's generating then you can call `$sql = $this->db->get_compilted_select()` instead of `->get()` and it will return it in `$sql` without running the query.

Comment: Could also be your `or_like()` statements are matching the `stu_student = 1` record. Are the conditions set so `stu_student = 0` OR the `like` conditions can be true?

Comment: @vickel.......you were right, i was making mistake in grouping of multiple where , thanks for reminding me of that codeignitor userguide